# Issue with log4j 2.17.0 update: ClassNotFoundException SetUtils

Tags: java, log4j, log4shell

After the version bump to log4j 2.17.0 this exception was raised during the unit tests:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SetUtils
```

How to work around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trial and error [I found here](https://www.mail-archive.com/notifications@ofbiz.apache.org/msg46549.html) that upgrading to log4j 2.17.0 implies a new dependency [`log4j-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where this class is specified?
I try to find it and do not see it?
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.17.0/log4j-web/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html

Comment: That's an internal class -- you should not be pulling log4j-web dependency for the sake of using such util/private class. @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki post is the correct solution.

Comment: @PaoloC I don't use this internal class, in my case it's tomcat that (somehow) has this internal dependency. This answer is written only to help the people that has this problem.

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend to add "Tomcat" in the title, and also specify Tomcat's version. Otherwise this seems a general question, but it only applies to Application Servers (configured in certain ways).

Comment: This link also helps: https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@tomcat.apache.org/msg00499.html

Answer (score 1):

I had asked Log4j developers what to do with this.
The class is treated as internal and shall not be used.

See. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3309

The code which might be used to replace the class shall be more less like below (using: `org.apache.commons.collections4`)

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.SetUtils;

// generic
Predicate<E> predicate = x -> (doSthWith(x));
final Set<E> resultSet = SetUtils.predicatedSet(setOfElements, predicate);
final String[] array = (String[]) resultSet.toArray();

// for example
Predicate<String> containsString = str -> (str.startsWith(stringToSearch));
final Set<String> resultSet = SetUtils.predicatedSet(setOfStrings, containsString);
final String[] arrayOfStrings= (String[]) resultSet.toArray();
```